# Selection Behavior become weird in charts_flutter

Tags: flutter, charts

I am building an app with Flutter, and package charts_flutter(which had been archived). And a problem appear make me confuse. The selection behavior doesn't works as my expect
[Scatter point and line selection not in a vertical line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDkO4.png)
I use an Scatter plot line chart([chart link](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/combo_charts/scatter_plot_line)) but the problem occurs that when i select a point of scatter event, it select a point in line and it is not the nearest point to the scatter point. Here is my code

```
SizedBox(
            height: 240,
            child: charts.TimeSeriesChart(
              [
                charts.Series<num, DateTime>(
                  id: 'signal2Chart',
                  domainFn: (_, int? index) {
                    if (index != null) {
                      final DateTime date = datas!.time[index].beginningOfDay;
                      return date;
                    } else {
                      throw Exception("Chart index null");
                    }
                  },
                  measureFn: (num o, _) {
                    return o;
                  },
                  seriesColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                      widget.stockModel?.stockData.color ??
                          AppColors.semantic_02),
                  data: datas!.c,
                )
                  ..setAttribute(charts.rendererIdKey, 'scatterChart')
                  ..setAttribute(
                      charts.measureAxisIdKey, "secondaryMeasureAxisId"),
                if (widget.data?.cBUYDATE != null)
                  charts.Series<TopSignalDetailModel, DateTime>(
                    id: 'Annotation Series 2',
                    colorFn: (_, __) =>
                        charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault,
                    domainFn: (TopSignalDetailModel event, _) =>
                        event.cBUYDATE!,
                    measureFn: (TopSignalDetailModel event, __) {
                      final int index = datas!.time.indexWhere((element) {
                        final int compare =
                            element.beginningOfDay.compareTo(event.cBUYDATE!);
                        switch (compare) {
                          case 0:
                            return true;
                          default:
                            return false;
                        }
                      });
                      return index > -1
                          ? datas!.o.elementAt(index)
                          : event.cBUYPRICE;
                    },
                    radiusPxFn: (_, __) => 5.0,
                    data: [widget.data!],
                  )
                    ..setAttribute(charts.boundsLineRadiusPxKey, 3.5)
                    ..setAttribute(
                        charts.measureAxisIdKey, "secondaryMeasureAxisId"),
              ],
              animate: false,
              layoutConfig: charts.LayoutConfig(
                bottomMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.defaultSpec,
                leftMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.defaultSpec,
                rightMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.defaultSpec,
                topMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.defaultSpec,
              ),
              domainAxis: charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
                  tickFormatterSpec:
                      charts.BasicDateTimeTickFormatterSpec.fromDateFormat(
                          TimeUtilities.dateMonthTimeFormat),
                  tickProviderSpec: const charts.AutoDateTimeTickProviderSpec(),
                  showAxisLine: true,
                  // viewport: charts.NumericExtents(minX, maxX),
                  renderSpec: const charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
                      axisLineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(
                        dashPattern: [4],
                        thickness: 0,
                        color: charts.Color(r: 74, g: 85, b: 104),
                      ),
                      labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(fontSize: 9),
                      lineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(dashPattern: [4]))),
              primaryMeasureAxis: const charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                showAxisLine: false,
                renderSpec: charts.NoneRenderSpec(),
              ),
              secondaryMeasureAxis: const charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                showAxisLine: true,
                tickProviderSpec: charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(
                  zeroBound: false,
                ),
                renderSpec: charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
                  axisLineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(
                    dashPattern: [4],
                    thickness: 0,
                    color: charts.Color(r: 74, g: 85, b: 104),
                  ),
                  labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(fontSize: 9),
                  lineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(dashPattern: [4]),
                ),
              ),
              defaultRenderer: charts.PointRendererConfig(),
              customSeriesRenderers: [
                charts.LineRendererConfig(
                  smoothLine: true,
                  includeArea: true,
                  // includePoints: true,
                  customRendererId: 'scatterChart',
                ),
              ],
              behaviors: [
                charts.LinePointHighlighter(
                    symbolRenderer: CustomTooltipRenderer(_ToolTipMgr.instance,
                        size: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
                        fontSize: 10) // add this line in behaviours,
                    ),
              ],
              selectionModels: [
                charts.SelectionModelConfig(
                  type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,
                  changedListener: (charts.SelectionModel model) {
                    if (model.hasDatumSelection) {
                      final List<String> data = [];
                      print(model.selectedDatum.length);
                      if (model.selectedDatum.length > 1) {
                        late TopSignalDetailModel topSignalStockModel;
                        late num price;
                        for (var element in model.selectedDatum) {
                          print(element.datum);
                          if (element.datum is TopSignalDetailModel) {
                            topSignalStockModel = element.datum;
                          } else if (element.datum is num) {
                            price = element.datum;
                          }
                        }
                        data.add(
                            "Ngày ${TimeUtilities.commonTimeFormat.format(topSignalStockModel.cBUYDATE!)}");
                        data.add("Giá mua ${topSignalStockModel.cBUYPRICE}");
                        data.add("Giá $price");
                      } else {
                        final index = model.selectedDatum.first.index ?? 0;
                        data.add(
                            "Ngày ${TimeUtilities.commonTimeFormat.format(datas!.time.elementAt(index))}");
                        data.add("Giá ${model.selectedDatum.first.datum}");
                      }
                      _ToolTipMgr.instance.setData(data);
                    } else {
                      _ToolTipMgr.instance.setData([]);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

And below is my chart when i include points in line. there is a point right below the event but is not selected.
[Line with point render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvwEa.png)
Code run with no error throw so i can not find out what happen to my code. Here my flutter doctor
[Flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWHFc.png)

Can some one find me a solution.
Sory if my English is unintelligible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem with your selection behavior is caused by the fact that you are using a custom renderer for your scatter plot, which is not working properly with the LinePointHighlighter behavior that you have added to the chart.

To fix this issue, you could try removing the custom renderer and using the default renderer for the scatter plot, which should work properly with the LinePointHighlighter behavior. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to use the default renderer:

```
    SizedBox(
  height: 240,
  child: charts.TimeSeriesChart(
    [
      charts.Series<num, DateTime>(
        id: 'signal2Chart',
        domainFn: (_, int? index) {
          if (index != null) {
            final DateTime date = datas!.time[index].beginningOfDay;
            return date;
          } else {
            throw Exception("Chart index null");
          }
        },
        measureFn: (num o, _) {
          return o;
        },
        seriesColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
            widget.stockModel?.stockData.color ??
                AppColors.semantic_02),
        data: datas!.c,
      ),
      if (widget.data?.cBUYDATE != null)
        charts.Series<TopSignalDetailModel, DateTime>(
          id: 'Annotation Series 2',
          colorFn: (_, __) =>
              charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault,
          domainFn: (TopSignalDetailModel event, _) =>
              event.cBUYDATE!,
          measureFn: (TopSignalDetailModel event, __) {
            final int index = datas!.time.indexWhere((element) {
              final int compare =
                  element.beginningOfDay.compareTo(event.cBUYDATE!);
              switch (compare) {
                case 0:
                  return true;
                default:
                  return false;
              }
            });
            return index > -1
                ? datas!.o.elementAt(index)
                : event.cBUYPRICE;
          },
          radiusPxFn: (_, __) => 5.0,
          data: [widget.data!],
        )
          ..setAttribute(charts.boundsLineRadiusPxKey, 3.5)
          ..setAttribute(
              charts.measureAxisIdKey, "secondaryMeasureAxisId"),
    ],
    animate: false,
    layoutConfig: charts.LayoutConfig(
      bottomMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.defaultSpec,
      leftMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.defaultSpec,
      rightMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.defaultSpec,
      topMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.defaultSpec,
    ),
    domainAxis: charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
        tickFormatterSpec:
            charts.BasicDateTimeTickFormatterSpec.fromDateFormat(
                TimeUtilities.dateMonthTimeFormat),
        tickProviderSpec: const charts.AutoDateTimeTickProviderSpec(),
        showAxisLine: true,
        // viewport: charts.NumericExtents(minX, maxX),
        renderSpec: const charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
            axisLineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(
              dashPattern: [4],
              thickness: 0,
              color: charts.Color(r: 74, g: 85, b: 104),
            ),
            labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(fontSize: 9),
            lineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(dashPattern: [4]))),
    primaryMeasureAxis: const charts.NumericAxisSpec(
      showAxisLine: false,
      renderSpec: charts.NoneRenderSpec(),
    ),
    secondaryMeasureAxis: const charts.NumericAxisSpec(
      showAxisLine: true,
      tickProviderSpec: charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(
        zeroBound: false,
      ),
      renderSpec: charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
        axisLineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(
          dashPattern: [4],
```

Comment: your answer lacks of last part of the code meaning that your last part code is the same with my code?

Comment: I thought i had found what is problem. if list chart domain data have values with the same value, you are only allowed to choose the first value(by index) with the sames value as others. So if the value in the vertical line with my event value has the same as value with some of foward values, you cannot select this value, so it will select another point which is not in the vertical line. I think i must custom that package, but still have no idea where to start. Do you have any suggestion?